# Post de um objeto JSon para Webservice através de AJAX

Tags: javascript, java, json

Estou tentando enviar um objeto no formato JSon para meu Webservice em Java pelo AJAX, mas não tive êxito, já testei formatos errados, que não são JSon's, como "string", e o banco relata erro devidamente, e portanto deveria relatar que o objeto foi salvo, de mesma forma o html também não retorna o 'alert'.
Segue abaixo meu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js.download"></script>
 <script src="scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js.download"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
                    var myJSon = {"Aluno":"nome", "Respostas":[], "Sessao":[] };
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Servidor/server',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(myJSon),
                    sucess: function (data){
                        alert('Sucess');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está criando um objeto dentro de um local indevido, de acordo com a  sintaxe, para corrigir, muda a posição de criação para antes da chamada do Ajax e tudo irá funcionar!

```
var myJSon = {"Aluno":"nome", "Respostas":[], "Sessao":[] };

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/Servidor/server',
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify(myJSon),
  sucess: function (data){
      alert('Sucess');
  },
  error: function () {
      alert('Error');
  }
});
```

Em caso de duvidas também pode consultar [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), vlw!

Comment: muito obrigado, agora o html alerta erro, mas nada de aparecer no console do servidor, vou continuar procurando, mas novamente obrigado

Comment: Entendi, então cheque se está configurado da forma correta seus sripts de back-end, um bom site para estudos é o MDN e PHP oficial. Essa linha do PHP funciona com seu código acima:
<?php
print_r(json_encode($_post['Aluno']));
?>

Comment: O back-end está em Java

Comment: ai eu não manjo, mas edita lá em cima a categoria e coloca java também, tenta descrever para alguém para ajudar com java sobre a questão atual, tipo, como faço para receber os dados via Ajax com Java no back-end.